# Is this matrix diagonalizable, and if so what is it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 5 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Is it diagonalizable? I think it is, but when I try to test the eigenvalues (which are $3$, $-2$, $-1$), I get stuck. Specifically, on the test of eigenvalue $-2$, I cannot seem to find a basis for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is diagonalizable. When you do the RREF for $[A - \lambda I]v_2 = [A + 2 I] v_2 = 0$, you get $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{3}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, so pick $v_2 = (0, -3, 4)$.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all eigenvalues ($-2,-1,3$) are different, yes it is.

We can see this fact also knowing with the information of Jordan canonical form. It says that all of eigenvalues squares have to be $1\times 1$ matrices.

Comment: Right, which is what I thought. If that is the case, take the eigenvalue -2. What would the eigenvector be?

Comment: If you know about Jordan canonical form, all of them need to be $1\times 1$ square.